# My program does not continue after I call a function to scan something? Can someone find out whats wrong? (long but please help!)

Tags: c

So the first part is I get an input from the user which for this instance is '1' as a character value which is received from another function.

```
printf ("\nPlease enter 1, 2, 3 or q: ");

    option = validateoption();
```

In the validateoption function:

```
int validateoption () {  // VALIDATE OPTION FOR FIRST MENU INPUT

int keeptrying = 1, rc;
char after, i;

do
{
    rc = scanf ("%c%c", &i, &after);
    if (i == 'q')
    {
        break;
    }
        else if (rc == 0)
        {
            printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
            clear();
        }
            else if (after != '\n')
            {
                printf (" **Trailing characters try again: ");
                clear();
            }
                else if (i < '1' || i > '3')
                {
                    printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
                }
                    else
                    {
                        keeptrying = 0;
                    }

} while (keeptrying == 1);

return i;

}
```

So character value of '1' is entered and then the transaction function is called

```
    do
    {
        transaction(accounts, debcred, amount);
    } while (option == '1');
```

This is where the problem happens. In the transaction function it has a for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    printf ("Enter an account number (between 1000 and 3999): ");
    accounts[i] = validateaccount();

    debcred[i] = validatedebcred();

    amount[i] = validateamount();

    totalinput++;
}
```

and it calls to the validateaccount function to obtain a valid input. But in this function:

```
int validateaccount() {  // VALIDATE INPUT FOR ACCOUNT # IN TRANSACTION FUNCTION

int keeptrying = 1, rc;
long i;
char after;

do
{
    rc = scanf ("%ld%c", &i, &after);

    if (rc == 0)
    {
        printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
        clear();
    }
        else if (after != '\n')
        {
            printf (" **Trailing characters try again: ");
            clear();
        }
            else if (i < 1000 || i > 3999)
            {
                printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
            }
                else
                {
                    keeptrying = 0;
                }

} while (keeptrying == 1);

return i;

}
```

I enter an input and then the program stops running! I would enter like 1000 then it just does nothing after that. It doesn't end it just does nothing, then ill enter more numbers and it becomes an invalid input! I have no idea whats going on can someone see the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Im an idiot. It wasn't showing anything after the final input because there was no printf statement again to show the user what to input!

Comment: It is aggravating how literal computers are following directions.